# How to find redundant paths (subpaths) in the trajectory of a moving object?

Tags: python, python-2.7, video-tracking

I need to track a moving deformable object in a video (but only 2D space). How do I find the paths (subpaths) revisited by the object in the span of its whole trajectory? For instance, if the object traced a path, p0-p1-p2-...-p10, I want to find the number of cases the object traced either p0-...-p10 or a sub-path like p3-p4-p5. Here, p0,p1,...,p10 represent object positions (in (x,y) pixel coordinates at the respective instants). Also, how do I know at which frame(s) these paths (subpaths) are being revisited?

Comment: What are p0, p1, etc.? Are they pixels? Regions of the image? Nodes of a graph? If they are nodes of a graph, count off each node as it is visited while checking whether you have already visited the node before. If you have visited the node before, you have a retraced "path" of length 1. If the next node is labeled with the successive number, you grow that retraced path by 1. Continue in this fashion until you reach a node that is not labeled with the number succeeding the number of the previously visited node.  You will potentially accumulate a list of retraced paths. Also, ...

Comment: ...nodes will potentially have multiple numbers associated with them, one number each time it was visited by the object, the number being determined by the order in which it was visited (the ordinal first, second, 123rd, ...).

Comment: Thank you. In my case p0,p1,, etc. are pixel coordinates representing the object center positions at those instants.

Answer (score 0):

I would first create a detection procedure that outputs a list of points visited along with their video frame number. Then use list exploration functions to know how many redundant suites are found and where.

As you see I don't write your code. If you need anymore advise please ask!